# Angular in external file not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

To make it easy to understand, I made two examples of which one works and the other doesn't.

The first one is the script content inside html page and it is working fine.

```
        <html ng-app>
          <head>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <input type="text" ng-model="helloAngular" />
            <h1>{{helloAngular}}</h1>
          </body>
        </html>
```

This is the part of code that is not working (inside the same html page):

```
        <div ng-app="app">
            <p>Try to change the names.</p>
            <div ng-controller="personController">
                <p>
                    First Name:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    Last Name:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    Full Name:
                    {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the js file:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("personController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

It looks like this after compiling:

[image: It looks like this]

The javascript file is properly included into html (I tried $(document).ready()). Ofcourse, for the second example I removed ng-app attribute from the html tag.

Also tried clearing cookies and cache, but no success. The same thing happening in other browsers.

I was using that Angular file for other app functions, and they are all not working anymore. It stopped working when I opened the file and added new controller into the existing app module. To be sure, I tried the above example within the new .js file and also tried to comment out all the previous angular code in mentioned angular file.

**EDIT 1.**

Ok, I copy/pasted angular code inline in html, but still no luck.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module("app", []).controller("personController", [$scope, function ($scope) {
                $scope.firstName = "John";
                $scope.lastName = "Doe";
            }]);
        </script>


        <div ng-app="app">
            <p>Try to change the names.</p>
            <div ng-controller="personController">
                <p>
                    First Name:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    Last Name:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    Full Name:
                    {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Using the @BarouchKandov plunker project I recreated the problem, and it works under the plunker project, but the same piece of code doesn't work in my ASP.NET project.

[Plunker project](https://plnkr.co/edit/05pv4kV7hoWjln9DcWf9?p=preview)

I have also tried with removing the [$scope, ...] brackets

Comment: can you provide any link instead of code snippets?

Comment: your controller is not loaded properly ,so changes in controller is not reflecting in view.

Comment: I have created a plunker project with your two examples: https://plnkr.co/edit/anfafebeMQDVA08XxHws?p=preview

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, but still no luck. Please check the post edit. I inserted the angular code into inline script tag and it still doesn't work. It seems like it doesn't recognize module and controller